# After setting BoxLayout to my JPanel, my image is not displayed properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, boxlayout

```
package BlackjackPanels;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class MainPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel background;
    BufferedImage backgroundImage=ImageIO.read(new File("src/BlackjackImages/blackjackBackground.jpg"));

    public MainPanel() throws IOException { 
        super("Alan's Blackjack");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        background = new JPanel() 
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {       
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };
        add(background);
        loadGame();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    public void loadGame() throws IOException {

        background.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        PlayerPanel player=new PlayerPanel();
        DealerPanel dealer=new DealerPanel();
        OptionPanel option= new OptionPanel();
            dealer.setBox();
        JPanel gameBoard=new JPanel();
        gameBoard.setOpaque(false);
        gameBoard.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gameBoard,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        gameBoard.add(dealer);
        gameBoard.add(player);
        background.add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        background.add(option, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainPanel game = new MainPanel();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

DealerPanel:

```
public class DealerPanel extends JPanel {

private JLabel moneyAmt;
private JLabel betAmt;
private JPanel status;

public DealerPanel() {
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    setOpaque(false);
    setFocusable(true);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY), "DEALER"));
    moneyAmt = new JLabel("Your money:");
    betAmt = new JLabel("Your bet:");
    moneyAmt.setForeground(Color.red);
    betAmt.setForeground(Color.red);
}

public void setBox() {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    add(moneyAmt);
    add(betAmt);
}
}
```

PlayerPanel:

```
package BlackjackPanels;
public class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {

    Image cardImg=Card.loadCardImage();

    public PlayerPanel() throws IOException {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));
        setOpaque(false);
        setFocusable(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY), "PLAYER"));

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(cardImg,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

My program displayed properly until I called setLayout(newBoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); in the constructor of DealerPanel. After I called the function, my entire program was extended to the right, showing white space. Before, it was set showing a image of 600 by 600 with buttons (OptionPanel) added at the bottom. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because you are specifying `this` in constructor (this JPanel may not be completely initialized). Try replacing:

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

with:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Note: From what we see in your code here, replacing this `BoxLayout` with a `BorderLayout` should not have any impact on your layout inside this panel because you don't add any component to this panel in your code. If this is not the case, please read [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) Javadoc.

Comment: Hi xav, thanks for the reply. Changing from a BoxLayout to BorderLayout did make it work. However, I still don't understand why my code above produced such a weird result. To test what you were saying, I took the setLayout method out of my constructor and made a separate method where I called setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); and then added the components to it. This, however, produced the same odd result as my original code. "this" passed to the setLayout method must have been fully initialized in this case, no?

Comment: Maybe your issue is not only due to the fact that you're using `this`... it may come from the `BoxLayout` itself. If you post the code that adds components to your `DealerPanel` I could help you more (seeing your code I may tell you how to use a `GridbagLayout` instead)

Comment: Note: if you moved `setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));`  outside `DealerPanel` constructor, then you should not use `this` anymore but `DealerPanel` instance instead.

Comment: I have put an updated version of code. Basically, I added a separate method setBox() in the DealerPanel and called the method on MainPanel. Please take a look.

Comment: The new code looks fine. I think it should now do what you expected, doesn't it? By the way, looking at the components you add in this `DealerPanel`, you could also have used a `new GridLayout(2, 1)` instead of a `BoxLayout`. Now I understand why using a `BorderLayout` didn't work (adding two components without layout constraints)

Comment: My new code using the BoxLayout produces same wrong display.. The only way I could make it work correctly so far is by using a layout other than boxlayout. (borderlayout, or gridlayout like you suggested) I wish I could understand the problem..:(

Comment: If you talk about the fact that the `DealerPanel` does not take all possible width, it's due to `BoxLayout` normal behavior: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) says: _"BoxLayout attempts to arrange components at their preferred widths (for horizontal layout)"_ 
In fact I don't like `BoxLayout` that much because its layout also depends on your current regional settings (Locale), for left-to-right orientation for example (e.g. Arabic countries will see your components laid out from right to left instead of left to right and chinese from bottom to top).